# MariaDB default user accounts created during installation?

Tags: mariadb, users

I have installed MariaDB 5.5.57 and phpMyAdmin 5.1.0 on my QNAP NAS.
I notice that 7 user accounts were created during installation;
[image]

What's the purpose of the three "Any" accounts, and do I need them?  (In other words, can they be safely deleted?)
Then why are there 4 "root" accounts? And again, do I need all of them?

Any help is appreciated.
Many thanks in advance - from a newbee :-)

Comment: *What's the purpose of the three "Any" accounts, and do I need them?* This is accounts which have `USAGE` privilege only (which is a synonim for `NO PRIVILEGES`) - so they can be used for connection testing purposes only. *Then why are there 4 "root" accounts?* These are accounts with different host part - so you can access regardless the variant of your PC name will be distinguished (IPv4, IPv6, DNS-name, NetBIOS name). *do I need all of them?* I do not recommend to do something with 4 `root` accounts. `Any` accounts may be, of course, deleted, but I do not see the reason for to do this.

Comment: Ok, thank you for taking the time to answer.
I took my chances and deleted all the Any accounts, as well as the "Test" database and the extra root accounts except the one with my password.
It didn't seem to affect any of my apps using MariaDB  

Comment: What `root` account you have stored? with what `host` part?

Comment: I kept the one linked to localhost and deleted all the others.